# How many of each kind of fruit was bought?

Tags: diophantine-equations, linear-diophantine-equations

A customer bought a dozen of apples and oranges $\$1.32$. If an apple costs $3$ cents more than oranges and more apple than oranges were bought, using linear diophantine equation find,how many of each kind of fruit was bought.

**My Attempt:**

$$x \leftarrow   number\ of\ apples$$

$$y \leftarrow  number \ of\  oranges$$
$$z \leftarrow  cost \ of \ an \ orange \ in \ \underline{dollar}$$
so then I get
$$x+y=12$$ and
$$x(z+0.03)+yz=1.32$$
$$0.03x+12z=1.32$$
multiplying the both sides by 100 then
$$3x+1200z=132$$
$$x+400z=44$$
then the general solution of $x+400z=44$ is $z=t,x=44-400t$ where $t \in \mathbb{Z}$

since $z,x>0$
$$t>0 \ and \ t<0.11$$
then I stuck, answer of this problem got $z$ as cost of an orange in cents but here I got $z$ as cost of an orange in dollar where am I wrong? why my method is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming that $z=t$ (the price of an orange in dollars) is an integer (why?) and you conclude that $0<t<0.11$ which implies that such integer does not exist.

On the other hand, by assumption $100z$ is an integer (the price of an orange in cents) and $x$ is an integer in $(0,12)$ such that, by your work,
$$x=44-400z=4\underbrace{(11-100z)}_{\in\mathbb{N}^+}\in \{4,8\}.$$
Since $x>y$ (more apples than oranges), it follows that $x=8$ and $z=0.09$.

Comment: I understood your way but my problem is Why my method is wrong?

Comment: You are assuming that $z=t$ (the price of an orange in dollars) is an integer (why?) and you conclude that $0<t<0.11$ which implies that such integer does not exist.

Comment: I used methode of general solution of diophantine equation but finally my answer is wrong if I use $z$ as in dollar this way is correct

Comment: Using $z$ as the price in dollars is OK. Your equation $=44−400$ is correct. It is wrong assuming that $z$ is an integer.

Comment: If so how do I use Diophantine equation  for this?

Comment: Diophantine equation means that the variables are integers so you should use $t=100z$ and solve $x+4t=44$.

Comment: I got what my mistake as you said but then how can I used diophantine equation for this?

Comment: Ohh nice thank you for your help

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

More apples were bought than oranges.

Say, number of apples bought $= 6+x$, number of oranges bought $= 6-x \,$
where $0 \lt x \lt 6$

$ (6+x)(z+3)+(6-x)z = 132$ where $z$ is in cents.

$ 4z + x = 38$

$ 32 \lt 4z \lt 38$

$ z = 9$

Now you can find $x = 2$ so $8$ apples and $4$ oranges.